# href in modal dialog in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, modal-dialog

this is my first bootstrap project. i try to open a url if the user clicks the yes button in a modal dialog. But it wont work as suspected:

This is my code:

```
<div class="modal inmodal fade" id="myModal6" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title">Delete?</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <p><strong>You like to delete the files?</strong></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-white" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="index.php?delete=yes">Yes</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

The Yes-Button didnt work. Maybe someone can help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of button try a tag like this

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="index.php?delete=yes">Yes</a>
```